# Sympy reconfigures the randomness seed

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, sympy, random-seed

The use of Python symbolic computation module "Sympy" in a simulation is very difficult, I need to have reliable fixed inputs, for that I use the seed() in the random module.
However every time I call a simple sympy function, it seems to overwrites the seed with a new value, thus getting new output every time. I have searched a little bit and [found](https://goo.gl/Nmkh1V) [this](http://goo.gl/rJsWhq). But neither of them has a solution.

Consider this code:

```
from sympy import *
import random
random.seed(1)
for _ in range(2):
    x = symbols('x')
    equ = (x** random.randint(1,5)) ** Rational(random.randint(1,5)/2)
    print(equ)
```

This outputs

```
(x**2)**(5/2)
x**4
```

on the first run, and

```
(x**2)**(5/2)
(x**5)**(3/2)
```

On the second run, and every-time I run the script it returns new output. I need a way to fix this to enforce the use of seed().

Comment: I tested this in the development version of SymPy (soon to be released as a new version) and it seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help? From the docs on [random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html):

"You can instantiate your own instances of Random to get generators that don’t share state"

Usage:

```
import random
# Create a new pseudo random number generator
prng = random.Random()
prng.seed(1)
```

This number generator will be unaffected by sympy